# English term for a country's ability to maintain energy stock

Tags: terminology

I am translating a document and I wonder if there is an equivalent English term for a word "**a country's ability to keep good stock of the country's energy or resources such as food, electricity, or energy in general**"

For example :

> This country expects to keep good stock of the country's
>   water resources during this long dry season during 2019.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The term for storing up a large stock of goods or materials (including energy) is *stockpiling*.

Goods which have been deliberately stored up to be used in times of shortages are known as *reserves*. This term is commonly used for both energy and water. Bodies of water held for use during water shortages are known as *reservoirs*.

> This country expects to keep **adequate [reserves of water](https://wwf.panda.org/our_work/water/freshwater_inititiaves/water_reserves_initiative/)** during this long dry season during 2019.
>
> **[Energy reserves](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/energy-reserves.html)** are projected on the basis of geologic and engineering data (proved reserves) and projection drawn on the basis of proved reserves.

Answer (score -1):

A stored surplus of fuels is a reserve [1](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/energy-reserves.html)

> Estimated quantity of energy source (such as coal, gas, or oil) known
>   with reasonable certainty to exist, and which can be recovered with
>   presently available technology at an economically viable cost. Energy
>   reserves are projected on the basis of geologic and engineering data
>   (proved reserves) and projection drawn on the basis of proved reserves

For foodstuff and other materials, then referring to it as a stockpile would be more appropriate. [2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stockpile)

> - A supply of material, as a pile of gravel in road maintenance.
> - A large supply of some metal, chemical, food, etc., gathered and held in reserve for use during a shortage or during a
>     period of higher prices.
> - A quantity, as of munitions or weapons, accumulated for possible future use.

Comment: Hi Ratstool, welcome to ELL! Please could you add sources to back up your answer? Feel free to use the [ELL help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how to answer